# AWS is sending emails thread safe

Tags: thread-safety, amazon-web-services

Using `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.sendEmail() ;` as per java docs

> All service calls made using this client are blocking, and will not return until the service call completes.

Quick question is, is it thread safe?. Can multiple threads be using same instance of `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient` to call `sendEmail()` in parallel? Like, suppose, multiple users of my website trying to register on the website concurrently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the answer I got from AWS:

Hi,

You should be able to use the same `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient()` object to send using multiple threads.

Regards,
Rohan

Comment: Fantastically detailed answer from Amazon to complement their fantastically detailed javadoc. Gold star to them.

Comment: @murdoch haha true .. and notice in their answer "should "

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an updated answer since the original one is from 2012 and not very reassuring about the thread safety.

I am not sure in which version it was introduced, but in latest Java AWS SDK version available today (October 2016, version 1.11.43) the class is annotated as `@ThreadSafe`, so the sendEmail method can be assumed thread safe